# java.lang.Throwable: addInArray in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Here is the log,
this log shows as many times as the itemView's number.
but my app is still runing normally.

```
D/ViewGroup﹕ addInArray been called, this = android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{44dd4fc8 VFEDID 0,86-720,1140 7f0e01cc app:id/order_query_rv}call stack =
java.lang.Throwable: addInArray
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3742)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3566)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3511)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$4.addView(RecyclerView.java:538)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:83)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:6025)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:5983)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:5971)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1373)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1322)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:556)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2673)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2971)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15302)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15302)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15302)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15302)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15302)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15302)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15302)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2323)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2029)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:817)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:619)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:588)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:803)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5409)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:859)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:675)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I search for a long time ,and i still can't find a way to solve it 。
what cause this Throwable,how to solve it.

Activity

```
 public class OrderQueryActivity extends BaseActivity implements IOrderQueryView {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.base_mains);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dealTopMenu();
        this.iPresenter = new OrderQueryPresenter(OrderQueryActivity.this, new OrderQueryDao());
    }
@Override
    public void initView() {
        super.initView();
        final View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.layout_online_order_query, null);
        this.orderQueryTitle = (LinearLayout) contentView.findViewById(R.id.order_query_title_ll);
        this.addView(contentView);
        this.sumNum = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.order_num_tv);
        this.sumWeigh = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.order_weight);
        this.sumAmount = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.order_total_amount);
        this.rv = (RecyclerView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.order_query_recycler_view);
        this.rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        this.rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }
 @Override
    public void setAdapterForRv() {
        this.adapter = new OrderQueryAdapter(iPresenter);
        this.rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/order_query_title_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible">


        <TextView
            style="@style/online_order_query_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/total_order_num" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="72dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/order_num_tv"
                    style="@style/online_order_query_title_bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/order_number_example" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/online_order_query_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/order_number_unit" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/order_weight"
                    style="@style/online_order_query_title_bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/order_weight_example" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/online_order_query_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/weight_unit" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/order_total_amount"
                    style="@style/online_order_query_title_bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/order_total_amount_example" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/online_order_query_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/money_unit" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/order_query_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter

```
public class OrderQueryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderQueryAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private ArrayList<OrderBean> orderData;
        private IOrderQueryPresenter presenter;

        public OrderQueryAdapter(IOrderQueryPresenter presenter) {
            this.presenter = presenter;
            this.orderData = presenter.getOrderData();
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.query_online_order_card_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            OrderBean order = orderData.get(position);
            holder.dealerName.setText(order.getChannelName());
            holder.orderTime.setText(order.getOrderTime());
            holder.orderStatus.setText(order.getOrderStatus());
            holder.prodsNum.setText(order.getOrderSumNumber());
            holder.prodsWeight.setText(order.getWeight());
            holder.orderAmount.setText(order.getOrderSumPrice());
            holder.payment.setText(order.getPayAmount());
            OnDetailClickListener onDetailClickListener = new OnDetailClickListener(presenter, position);
            holder.orderContentll.setOnClickListener(onDetailClickListener);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return orderData.size();
        }

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView dealerName, orderTime, orderStatus, prodsNum, prodsWeight, orderAmount, payment;
            LinearLayout orderContentll;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                this.dealerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dealer_name);
                this.orderTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.order_time);
                this.orderStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.order_status);
                this.prodsNum = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.prod_count_online_order);
                this.prodsWeight = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.prod_weight_online_order);
                this.orderAmount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.prod_amount_online_order);
                this.payment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.payment_order_online);
                this.orderContentll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_order_content);
            }
        }

        static class OnDetailClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
            private int position;
            private IOrderQueryPresenter presenter;

            public OnDetailClickListener(IOrderQueryPresenter presenter, int position) {
                this.presenter = presenter;
                this.position = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.ll_order_content:
                        presenter.startOrderDetail(position);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/online_pay_card_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_dealer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dealer_name"
                    style="@style/online_order_query_primary_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/dealer_name" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/order_time"
                    style="@style/online_order_query_primary_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="@string/order_time_example" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/divider_one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_dealer"
                android:background="@drawable/single_divider_line_black"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_order_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/divider_one"
                android:background="@drawable/order_detail_selector"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/size14GreyText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/order_status_str" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/order_status"
                        style="@style/size14GreyText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                        android:text="@string/order_status_example" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/size14GreyText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/prod_num_str" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/prod_count_online_order"
                            style="@style/size14GreyText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                            android:text="@string/prod_num_example" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/size14GreyText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/prod_weight" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/prod_weight_online_order"
                            style="@style/size14GreyText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                            android:text="@string/weight_example" />

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/size14GreyText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/weight_unit" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/size14GreyText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/order_amount" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/prod_amount_online_order"
                            style="@style/online_order_query_primary_tv"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                            android:text="@string/order_amount_example" />

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/size14GreyText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/money_unit" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/divider_two"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_order_content"
                android:background="@drawable/single_divider_line_black"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/divider_two"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/size14GreyText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/already_payment" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/payment_order_online"
                        style="@style/online_order_query_primary_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                        android:text="@string/order_payment_example" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/size14GreyText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/money_unit" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/payment_detail_btn"
                        style="@style/iBtn_listView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/mm_title_btn_right"
                        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                        android:paddingRight="24dp"
                        android:text="@string/payment_detail" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/pay_online_order_btn"
                        style="@style/iBtn_listView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/mm_title_btn_right"
                        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                        android:paddingRight="24dp"
                        android:text="@string/pay_online_order" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which device are you testing on? That method does not really have any logs like this.

Comment: lenovo S850t ,API level is 19,Android version is 4.4.2 @yigit

Comment: please post your code

Comment: hope code is useful @Rohit_Ramkumar

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem ...

the problem disappeared after changing my code in fragment

from

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
 detailAdapter = new TitleAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),getActivity());//remove this
...
}
```

on

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    detailAdapter = new TitleAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager (),getActivity());//add this 
}
```